# Error when compiling: control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, c, theos

I'm trying to create my first mobilesubstrate tweak using theos on my device 
but when i'm compiliing im getting this error

> > Tweak.xm:23:1: error: control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

My Tweak.xm

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

static NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"/var/mobile/Library/Preferences/com.myplist.customwapprefs.plist"];

static BOOL pictureFit = NO;

static id connection = nil;

%hook WAPhotoMoveAndScaleViewController

- (BOOL)mustScaleToFill {


  pictureFit = [[plist objectForKey:@"photofit"]boolValue];  

  if (pictureFit) {
  return NO;
}
else if (!pictureFit) {
  return %orig;
}
}

%end
```

Please be specific i'm new to objective-c and all this, Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (pictureFit) {
  return NO;
}
else if (!pictureFit) {
  return %orig;
}
```

You don't need the second condition in the `else` part. Remove it and the compiler should be happy

Comment: Well, then try removing the `else` entirely. `if (pictureFit) { return NO; } return %orig;`

Comment: i got it work by adding `return %orig;` between the last 2 brackets,
and now i tested what you said in last comment and it worked as well thank you mate i will accept your answer instead of mine. Thanks